# How to do a partial deserialization with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

In my REST microservice, I request an object from another service that returns me a huge nested JSON, for example:

```
{
  "address": "19th Street",
  "contact_info": {
     "phones": {
        "home": {
           "first": {
             "another_nested": 1234
           }
        }
     } 
  } 
}
```

What I need to fetch this data from another service, perform a change only in the first field, and then send it via HTTP. What I'm trying to avoid is to deserialize everything on my side and having to maintain the classes here.
Is there a way to get the raw value of `contact_info` and just have the representation of address with Jackson? Something like this:

```
public class FullAddress {
  String address;
  RawValue contactInfo;
}
```

Comment: check this https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm

Comment: I appreciate any feedback on my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58102226/1426227).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The simplest approach would be using `JsonNode`:

```java
@Data
public class FullAddress {
    private String address;
    private JsonNode contactInfo;
}
```

Or either `Map<String, Object>`:

```java
@Data
public class FullAddress {
    private String address;
    private Map<String, Object> contactInfo;
}
```

It works for both serialization and deserialization.

---

If you, however, wants to store the raw JSON, then you could define a custom deserializer:

```java
public class RawJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
           throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) jp.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(jp);
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(node);
    }
}
```

And then use use it as follows:

```java
@Data
public class FullAddress {

    private String address;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = RawJsonDeserializer.class)
    private String contactInfo;
}
```

For serializing back, however, you can annotate the `contactInfo` field with [`@JsonRawValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonRawValue.html).

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: this does not work when using xml though, since Jackson will keep an internal JSON representation of the XML.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `JsonIgnoreProperties` on class [docs](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html) so it will ignore all other properties that not present in class

```
// To ignore any unknown properties in JSON input without exception:
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
```

Comment: I think the user want to deserialize data, change it, and serialize back into json. With `@JsonIgnoreProperties` you lose data which was ignored.

Comment: I think you've missed the point of the question. I've provided some solutions my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58102226/1426227).

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to always define model classes for your JSON string even if you need to map only a few fields from that JSON string. It's neater and in future anybody can easily add additional fields to model if it will be needed. Jackson supports partial mapping.

Complete working example in Kotlin:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import org.junit.Test

class Test {

    data class ModelInner(
            var attributeB1: String? = null,
    )

    data class ModelRoot(
            var attributeA2: List<ModelInner>? = null,
    )

    @Test
    fun test0() {
        val json = """
        {
            "attributeA0": "A0",
            "attributeA1": "A1",
            "attributeA2": [
                {
                    "attributeB0": "B00",
                    "attributeB1": "B01"
                },
                {
                    "attributeB0": "B10",
                    "attributeB1": "B11"
                }
            ]
        }
        """

        val om = ObjectMapper()
        om.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)

        val order = om.readValue(json, ModelRoot::class.java)

        print(order)
    }
}
```

Output:

> ModelRoot(attributeA2=[ModelInner(attributeB1=B01), ModelInner(attributeB1=B11)])

Answer (score 0):

There is also `ObjectMapper.readerForUpdating` which basically allows you to update in place a JSON object. There's not much documentation for it though:

https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readerForUpdating-java.lang.Object-

Example here:
https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/reader-for-updating.html

(Apologies for only a partial answer here - but it might be of use for someone)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to this is to use `@JsonAnyGetter` `@JsonAnySetter`. See the write-up here:
https://www.concretepage.com/jackson-api/jackson-jsonanygetter-and-jsonanysetter-example